# When Cain killed Abel who were the people he was afraid of?

Tags: cain, abel

I have thought about who were these people that lived outside of Eden or the confines of this setting that Cain feared would kill him for murdering his brother…I have been given no reasonable answer or answers seeming scripted as those captured in this forum…I do not think there is a sound answer but potentially probable…The story in Genesis is the story of God’s creation and his relationship with his “man and woman”…But there is a Parallel story in Ezekial 28..of how Lucifer and 1/3 of the heavenly host are cast out of heaven and it is these beings/people he was afraid of and who would recognize and also honor the mark of God placed on Cain…???